# how to find Qibla angle in Flutter Qibla

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

#Here is my current code to get angle but this is in decimal value I want to get in angle from 1 to 360 degree#

final qiblahDirection = snapshot.data;
var _angle = ((qiblahDirection.qiblah ?? 0) * (pi / 180) * -1

Answer (score 1):

```
double calculateQiblaDirection(Coordinates coordinates) {
    // Equation from "Spherical Trigonometry For the use of colleges and schools" page 50
    final longitudeDelta =
        radians(makkah.longitude) - radians(coordinates.longitude);
    final latitudeRadians = radians(coordinates.latitude);
    final term1 = sin(longitudeDelta);
    final term2 = cos(latitudeRadians) * tan(radians(makkah.latitude));
    final term3 = sin(latitudeRadians) * cos(longitudeDelta);

    final angle = atan2(term1, term2 - term3);
    return DoubleUtil.unwindAngle(degrees(angle));
  }
```

```
class DoubleUtil {
  static double normalizeWithBound(double value, double max) {
    return value - (max * ((value / max).floorToDouble()));
  }

  static double unwindAngle(double value) {
    return normalizeWithBound(value, 360);
  }

  static double closestAngle(double angle) {
    if (angle >= -180 && angle <= 180) {
      return angle;
    }
    return angle - (360 * (angle / 360).roundToDouble());
  }
}
```